# Ionic 2 Upgrade File Structure

Tags: ionic2

I am upgrading my app from `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` to `Ionic 2.0.0-rc.3` following this.

The [guide](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-200-rc0-2016-09-28) says the following:

> - Import and add each of your `custom components` and `pipes` to the
>     declarations array in `src/app/app.module.ts`.
> - Import and add each of your `providers` to the `providers` array in
>     `src/app/app.module.ts`.
> - Remove any use of the `providers`, `pipes` and `directives` arrays in
>     `@Component`.

**Question 1**

In the old `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` version, all the artifacts were just in the `app/pages` folder. With `Ionic 2.0.0-rc.3`, should they all just be in the `src/pages` folder with all the pages, or should they be seperated somewhere else?

**Question 2**

If I remove all `directives` from the `@Component` section of each page, where will those `directives` be defined?

e.g.

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'review.html',
  providers: [RatingService, JobService, UtilityService],
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, RatingComponentUpdateable, ControlMessages]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the **question 1**, actually you can decide how your project structure will be, and place the files where you want according to that (the only change will be in the path you use in the import statements). Ionic's default project's structure organizes things in terms of the *type* so by default you'd have something like this:

```
src
  ...
  pages
  pipes
  providers
  ...
```

One of the easiest ways to find out where to put things, is just by using the `ionic generate ... customName` command where the three dots can be `page`, `provider`, `pipe` and `directive`. That would create the artifact and place it where it should be.

You can also take a look at the [conference app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/tree/master/src) to know how Ionic team organizes the project and where everything is located.

That being said, I've been working on projects where *things* were organized in terms of *features*, so the project structure was something like this:

```
src
  feature1
    page1FromFeature1
    page2FromFeature1
    modelFromFeature1
    providerFromFeature1

  feature2    
    ...

  shared
    providers
    pages
    directives
    pipes
```

This is actually how Angular2 recommends to organize the project in the [Angular2 Style Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#04-07).

Regarding the **question 2**, directives should be included in the *NgModule declarations* array like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,

    // Pages
    ...

    // Pipes
    ...,

    // Directives
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,

    // Pages
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
                // Providers
                ...
             ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer

Comment: Glad I could help :)